# zoom out in the animator window is posible?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering, if I zoom out or in, in the animator window, it was possible, as I'm being complicated, to comfortably view the components in the animator window.

After looking for google in some post and forums, I did not find anything.

I ask this question, to know if this is available, and for other people, do not waste time reading things like [these](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/zoom-animator-controller-window.168053/), for after all I do not find anything.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english, I hope you can understand me.

Comment: P.D: Unity is very cool, but 4 years or more and even no zoom. Oh my goodness.

Comment: "do not waste time reading things like these" which of course leads us to waste time reading those things, thanks :) You might be able to control this with an editor script: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExtendingTheEditor.html